# Parsing SQL commands

Tags: java, sql, database

Basically I need to be able to parse a couple of SQL commands but I am not really sure of a good way.

Here is an example of the SQL commands

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (
        deptid INT CHECK(deptid > 0 AND deptid < 100), 
        dname CHAR(30), 
        location CHAR(10), 
        PRIMARY KEY(deptid)
    );

INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (16711,'A.Smith',22,'A',20);
```

I am coding in java so would split be the best way? Or should I write my own parser? If so, can someone give me an example of how to parse it specifically Strings that are surrounded by ' ' but might contain a ' inside. Also for the CREATE TABLE I need to some how separate the CHECK parameters

Comment: Depends on what you want out of the SQL code.  As a general rule, if you want fine detail, you'll need a full SQL parser.   If all you want is a *guess* at the tables involved, you can shred it with regexes.  So the answer depends on really what you think you need.

Comment: Well basically this is for a school project. I need to create my own DBMS so I need to be able to parse the SQL and then execute the actions

Comment: You are building a full SQL-based DBMS for a school project, from scratch?? Are you sure that is the requirement? You're in for a LOT of work.  You'll need a full SQL parser (or, at least a full parser for the part of SQL you intend to implement).  And if this is the task, the fact that you were considering Java text hacking to do it, suggests you don't have the background to do it.  What is the specific class you are taking?

Comment: Yes I understand it is a lot of work. The reason I wanted to do it by text hacking is we are also limited in the amount of SQL libraries we can use. This is for a Database class.

Comment: I'd expect you to *use* a Database in a DB class, not build one.  You won't get far trying to process SQL querires with text hacking.  People repeatedly try to do text hacking instead of real parsing, and it always ends painfully.

Comment: Unrelated but: I'm pretty sure you do **not** want to store the department name in a `CHAR(30)` column, but a `VARCHAR(30)` instead.

Comment: @user2574427, I'm going to concur with Ira that you have either misunderstood the requirements, or you have been ill prepared for it. That you would consider string splitting a viable option leads me to strongly urge you to consult your teacher for clarification. 

Parsing the SQL expressions and/or DDL statements, while non trivial, is amongst the easier bits of building a DBMS.

Would it be possible to reproduce the requirements verbatim as part of your question, the answer you need may not be the one asked for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in Java, I'd suggest looking into a Java-based parser generator with an available SQL grammar.    ANTLR seems like a good choice for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with using third parties, there are numerous parsers out there, including:

- [jOOQ, which has a parser](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/)
- [JsqlParser](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser)
- [General SQL Parser](https://www.sqlparser.com/)

You could parse your code like this:

```java
Queries queries = ctx.parser().parse("CREATE TABLE ...");
```

And then access the expression tree, e.g. to find the check constraint

```java
ctx.parser().parse("CREATE TABLE t (i int check (i > 0))")
    .forEach(q -> {
        if (q instanceof CreateTable ct) {
            for (TableElement e : ct.$tableElements()) {
                if (e instanceof Constraint c) {
                    println(c);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Note that as of jOOQ 3.17, [the traversal is still experimental](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/model-api/model-api-traversal/)

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ